# how it works sessions in passport-local and express

Tags: session, express, sails.js, passport.js

I'm trying to implement sessions in my sailsjs app. To make login I'm using passport and passport-local, by default passport manage session with serialize and deserialize but how it works, in the [documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/) talks about use express sessions too. My question is why I maybe have to use both, and how each it works?

This is to learn when use them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some examples for Sails/Passport/Passport-local integration:

1. https://gist.github.com/adityamukho/6260759
2. https://github.com/RelativeMedia/sails-PassportLocalMongoExample
3. https://github.com/cgmartin/sailsjs-angularjs-bootstrap-example
4. https://gist.github.com/adityamukho/6260759